# bootstrap nested column issue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

so here is my html :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row bg-white">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 p-2">
               <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-img">
                     <img src="#image" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-img-overlay">
                     <div class="card-title">
                        <h5><a href="#">Title</a></h5>
                     </div>
                     <div class="card-text">
                        some texts
                        <div class="dlbut p-2">
                           <center>
                              <h5><a href="#">link</a></h5>
                           </center>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 p-2">
               <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-img">
                     <img src="#image" class="img-fluid">
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-img-overlay">
                     <div class="card-title">
                        <h5><a href="#">Title</a></h5>
                     </div>
                     <div class="card-text">
                        some texts
                        <div class="dlbut p-2">
                           <center>
                              <h5><a href="#">link</a></h5>
                           </center>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

as you can see i have a column which is set to `col-lg-9 col-md-12` which i'm using it to have some sort of post loop in it. and each post gonna be the `col-lg-4 col-md-6`.
the problem is the first column works fine, it's full screen on medium sized devices but the second column doesn't act like it is expected on small devices. i set it `col-md-6` so it will be half of the screen wide on tablets for example and be full screen on mobile phones. but it won't.it will be half of the screen wide on small screens as well.
i also tried to add `col-sm-12` but same results again.
i looked diffrent topics,... most people didn't use `.row` which that isn't my case.
also i tried it without the second `container` and i got same results.

Answer (score 0):

few days ago i bought a license ,also if you like to use it free you can use it some days and can assist you : pingendo.com

is nice bootstrap but ,sometimes to speed up the things you should get some improvements

..anyway the thinks can look good like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <!--
  <div class="py-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row " draggable="true">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row bg-white">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 p-2">
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-img">
                      <img src="#image" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-img-overlay">
                      <div class="card-title">
                        <h5><a href="#">Title</a></h5>
                      </div>
                      <div class="card-text"> some texts <div class="dlbut p-2">
                          <center>
                            <h5><a href="#">link</a></h5>
                          </center>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 p-2">
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-img">
                      <img src="#image" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-img-overlay">
                      <div class="card-title">
                        <h5><a href="#">Title</a></h5>
                      </div>
                      <div class="card-text"> some texts <div class="dlbut p-2">
                          <center>
                            <h5><a href="#">link</a></h5>
                          </center>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>-->
  <!-- i did this with my Pingendo.com licensed -->
  <div class="row" draggable="true">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6" >
      <div class="card" >
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600?image=1074" alt="Card image">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <h4 class="card-title">John Catel</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Some example text.</p>
          <a href="#" class="link">See Profile</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/600/600?image=1074" alt="Card image">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <h4 class="card-title">John Catel</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Some example text.</p>
          <a href="#" class="link">See Profile</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried bootstrap 4 with

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-9">
         Level 1: .col-sm-9
         <div class="row">
         <div class="col-8 col-sm-6">
      Level 2: .col-8 .col-sm-6
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-6">
      Level 2: .col-4 .col-sm-6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nope, and I'm really confused 'cause I have done this and it has worked well but now even when I copy and past that code, it doesn't work...